# Start PHP script and then check the progress

Tags: php, mysql

i have a server, in which i have a mysql database and php, i have created an admin dashboard, and i want do this:
i want click a button to start a PHP script that update my database taking information from the web, then when i close my admin dashboard, i want for example after 3 hours check the status of the php script, for example with a progress bar, and if i want i want stop or pause this script is that possible?

i have think a loop like the while for instances:

```
while (buttonnotpressed && updatenotfinish)
{
 //update database
}
```

it's just an example, i'm looking for a lot of books, and i have searched on the web, but i can't find an answer...thanks!

Comment: You have to work with JS&AJAX

Comment: can you please make me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an async call from jquery to your php file

that file will then begin to work

then the other button does another async call to another php file that just writes some string to a file.

in your first file you now check in your while whether that one file contains some string

Comment: can you please make me an example?